# Python Selenium Chrome AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select a date from a drop down calendar.
I can't seem to get the correct element selected.

```
Start_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputStartInterval']/input")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Start_date).click('on_element=Start_date').key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

HTML input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid date-time-range-picker" type="text"

The reason I am using actionchains is because sendkeys is returning element not interactable.

Error Stack:-

> Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
>
> > AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Can you share the HTML.

Comment: Please provide code where you assign value to `to_element` variable

Comment: Just updated error, and added HTML.